# Team System "Not Downloaded" when it is downloaded

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Environment:

Team Foundation Server 2005
Visual Studio 2008

I have a reasonably large project with several code branches and several subfolders, solutions, etc. below each code branch.

In one particular branch, I have a folder with 3 subfolders. One of the folders is marked correctly as "Latest: Yes". However, the other two are marked as "Latest: Not downloaded". The files in the folders are marked similarly. Also, I cannot check out the files in these folders, since VS2008 does not recognize that I have the latest version.

I've looked through the security properties and they seem to be identical between the "good" folders and "bad" folders.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found and corrected the issue. It was that I was working in a particular code branch. However, a few of my solution files had code similar to this:

```
SccProjectName1 = $/MyProject/Release_3_3/Source/
```

when I am really working in a later release, Release 3.4. Since this was hard-coded into the solution file (how does it get there?), it was creating a new workspace for me, but only for the projects under that solution.

There must have been a conflict when it was looking to check out some of the project's files from an old branch when the remainder of my source code is mapped, in the workspace, to a later branch.

Once I removed this line of code from the solution file, everything works correctly.